# simple sql LIMIT statement

Tags: mysqli

Can anyone tell me if this is a valid sql statement?..

```
SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE foo="bar" ORDER BY foo_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5
```

I've searched online but the difficulty is a) inexperience and b) finding an example that contains the components I'm trying to assemble.

I want the statement to select ALL from the table where condition1 is true, then order the results by descending date, then LIMIT the returned rows to those specified...

many thanks to anyone that can give me a pointer in the right direction.

Scott

Comment: your statement seems ok. Anyway don't know why LIMIT 0,5 has 2 inputs... Want limit to 5 rows? Then LIMIT 5. The only that I miss is the ';' at the end

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: thanks. have tried via sql console in phpMyAdmin and the statement is fine so this Q is going nowhere. Apologies for wasting SO time and thanks for your blindingly obvious suggest... 'try it'.. hmmm, head up @#8 this morning then?!

Answer (score 0):

SELECT * FROM myTable WHERE foo="bar" ORDER BY foo_date DESC LIMIT 0, 5

...is fine - runs in phpMyAdmin no problem. I should have tested there before posting on SO - apologies.